# laplace transform ($t$-shifting)

Tags: laplace-method

Find the Laplace transform of:
$f(t)=\begin{Bmatrix}
\sin (\pi t), & 1<t<2\\ 
 0 & t<1\text{ or }t>2
\end{Bmatrix}$

---

I know how to find the transform by integration of $\sin( \pi t)$ but I'd like to know how to find the transform by using timeshifting (2. shift).

I know the result is: $F(s)=(e^{-s}-e^{-2s})F_{\sin( \pi t)}(s))=- \frac{\pi (e^{-s}-e^{-2s})}{s^2+\pi^2}$

I've tried to write the function using unit step functions ($\sin(\pi t) u(t-1)-\sin(\pi t) (u(t-2) $ ) but it doesn't seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $L\{u(t-c)\}=e^{-sc}/s$ and $L\{u(t-c)f(x-c)\}=e^{-sc}L\{f(t)\}$. Hence
$$
L\{\sin(\pi t) u(t-1)-\sin(\pi t) (u(t-2) \}=e^{-s}L\{\sin(\pi t+\pi)\}-e^{-2s}L\{\sin(\pi t+2\pi)\}\\
=-e^{-s}L\{\sin(\pi t)\}-e^{-2s}L\{\sin(\pi t)\}\\
=\frac{\pi (-e^{-s}-e^{-2s})}{s^2+\pi^2}
$$